# Compile error when trying to access StructuredBuffer

Tags: compute-shader, directcompute

I want to access a `StructuredBuffer<int>`in a compute shader but I get the error:

> Shader error in 'Particle.compute': array, matrix, vector, or indexable object type expected in index expression at Particle.compute(28) (on d3d11)

The code:

```
#pragma kernel CSMain
#include "Assets/Uplus/ZCommon/Resources/ImageProcessing/UplusDirectCompute.cginc"

struct Particle
{
    float3 Position;
    float Mass;
};

Texture2D<float2> _terTx;

ConsumeStructuredBuffer<Particle> currentBuffer;
AppendStructuredBuffer<Particle> nextBuffer;
StructuredBuffer<int> particleCount;

float3 _terPos;
float _terSize, _terPhysicalScale, _resolution;

SamplerState _LinearClamp;
SamplerState _LinearRepeat;

#define _gpSize 512

[numthreads(_gpSize, 1, 1)]
void CSMain(uint3 dispatchID : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    int flatID = dispatchID.x;
    int particleCount = particleCount[0];

    if (flatID >= particleCount) return;

    Particle particle = currentBuffer.Consume();

    //Commented the rest of code

    nextBuffer.Append(particle);
}
```

The error points the line `int particleCount = particleCount[0];`. Why is that?

The whole idea behind the shader is we have two buffers. We fill one with some data (we call each of them `Particle`) from CPU and then in the shader consume the data from the buffer, process it and then append to another buffer. then we swap buffers and do another iteration. The `particleCount` buffer holds the current count of `Particle`s that the buffer holds and the `if` clause prevents from consuming more Particles than available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old question so I assume you solved it, but here is the answer anyway:

You are declaring particleCount as an int when it already is a buffer.

Either change the name to `int currentParticleCount = particleCount[0];` or just don't use a temporary variable:

```
if (flatID >= particleCount[0]) return;
```